# Is there a way to create a foreign key constraint in mysql without validating the data?

Tags: mysql, database

I am importing a huge database. I created the schema, imported 100 GB of data, and then creating foreign key constraints. Creating foreign keys is taking a lot of time. I know that data is correct. I just need to add the foreign key without checking referential integrity.

- Server config
- 16 core xlarge instance on ec2
- memory 64G
- buffer pool 32G
- log file 1G
- buffer log 64M

Comment: Without referential integrity, it's not a foreign key, is it? Use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` before import and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` after.

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; .. your alter table sql .. SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

Comment: With foreign_key_checks = 0, adding constraint should take few seconds.  I made it 0 and created a FKEY. It took 1 hour (fkey between two tables with 143M rows and 2M rows).